# Use private-class members inside other private-class members

Tags: c++, class, object, pointers, g++

I am fairly new to C++ and am wondering if I am allowed to do the following:

```
class oFoo{
  ...
}

class Foo{
   int x;
   oFoo* oArray[x];
 public:
   Foo(int xVal);
   Foo~(); 
}
```

Am I allowed to use x as the bound for the array of pointers to class oFoo??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, only compile time constants are allowed. If you require dynamic array take a look at [std::vector](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Vector.html).